# Automapper expands all members when accessed from an OData action with EFCore using ProjectTo<Dto>

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, odata, automapper, .net-5

I'm trying to use Automapper to translate an IQueryable of type MyClass to an IQueryable of type MyClassDto.
The issue is that even though I've set explicit expansion for all members, it still expands all navigation properties.

The action is like this:

```cs
        [HttpGet]
        [EnableQuery]
        public ActionResult<IQueryable<MyClassDto>> GetCampaigns(ODataQueryOptions<MyClassDto> queryOptions)
        {
            if (queryOptions.SelectExpand != null)
            {
                return  Ok(_myClassService.AsQueryable().ProjectTo<MyClassDto>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider, null, queryOptions.SelectExpand.RawExpand.Split(',')));
            }
            
            return  Ok(_myClassService.AsQueryable().ProjectTo<MyClassDto>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider);
        }
```

The service method is nothing more than this:

```cs
public IQueryable<MyClass> AsQueryable() => _dbContext.MyClasses;
```

And the mapper configuration (The IAutomapperProfile interface is only used for reflection during startup):

```cs
    public class MyClassMapperConfiguration : Profile, IAutomapperProfile
    {
        public MyClassMapperConfiguration()
        {
            CreateMap<MyClass, MyClassDto>().ReverseMap().ForAllMembers(options => options.ExplicitExpansion());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're configuring the wrong map. You mean:

```
CreateMap<MyClass, MyClassDto>().ForAllMembers(options => options.ExplicitExpansion());
CreateMap<MyClassDto, MyClass>();
```

Comment: ForAllMembers() returns void, so ReverseMap() cannot come after it.

Comment: Yes. Then obviously `ReverseMap` must go. Updated.